# dtypes of DataFrame does not fit DataFrame.info()

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas DataFrame:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Float64Index: 880 entries, -440.0 to 439.0
Data columns (total 7 columns):
Channel 3 (A3)    880  non-null values
Channel 4 (A4)    880  non-null values
Channel 5 (A5)    880  non-null values
Channel 6 (A6)    880  non-null values
Channel 7 (B1)    880  non-null values
Channel 8 (B2)    880  non-null values
Channel 9 (B3)    880  non-null values
dtypes: float64(7)
```

So, here dtypes tells me that I have 7 times float64, but when I look at the member dtypes:

```
df.dtypes
Channel 3 (A3)    float64
Channel 4 (A4)    float64
Channel 5 (A5)    float64
Channel 6 (A6)    float64
Channel 7 (B1)    float64
Channel 8 (B2)    float64
Channel 9 (B3)    float64
dtype: object
```

Q1: Why does it say 'object' there?

Here is how I found this in the first place: 
I tried to save it as hdf and got a big fat performance warning:

```
/Users/maye/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.12.0_1007_g6eba2e4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/pytables.py:2325: PerformanceWarning: 
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->unicode,key->axis0] [items->None]

  warnings.warn(ws, PerformanceWarning)
/Users/maye/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.12.0_1007_g6eba2e4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/pytables.py:2325: PerformanceWarning: 
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->unicode,key->block0_items] [items->None]

  warnings.warn(ws, PerformanceWarning)
```

Q2: Are float64s not yet supported for HDF storage or is this a bug?

My pandas version: '0.12.0-1007-g6eba2e4'
And I created this dataframe first with read_excel, some clean-up and finished with a df.convert_objects() to get my float64 datatypes, or so I hoped.

Edit: The unicode column names were the cause of the warning, see also Jeff's comment below.

Comment: here's the unicode fix (will now raise for a table un py2) https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5387

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q1:

`DataFrame.dtypes` is a `Series` object which's dtype is an object. You can try:

```
print type(df.dtypes)
print df.dtypes.dtype
```

For Q2, I tried following code, no warnings, can you post some code that can reproduce the warnings?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5))
df.to_hdf("test.hdf", "data")
```

Comment: I found out that it's the unicode column names creating the performance warning. If you add to your code `df.columns = [unicode(i) for i in 'a b c d e'.split()]` and then try `df.to_hdf()` you should get the same warning.

Comment: unicode in py2 will always give you this warning, py3 will work normally (I *think* that PyTables 3.0.0 in py2 may work as well for unicode iirc)